# Where are all the important files and folders in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-systems

I searched on Google but i couldn't find a good page listing all the important system files and folders in Ubuntu. Does anyone know a good source?

Comment: define "important". for me my /home is much more important than anything else.

Comment: system imporant:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) describes the important places on a *nix system.

Answer (score 0):

In `/`. Poke around there for a bit to have a look - `/bin` is programs, `/usr/bin` are user programs - that will give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manpage for **hier**. Just type

```
man hier
```

in a console.

Comment: there is no man hier for ubuntu server?

Comment: Nowadays you can type man commands straight into google :-) Or use sites like http://linux.die.net/